# Google hangout API console appear to be broken

Tags: api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I had a working hangout app until yesterday - but now now I can no longer launch the app in the developer sandbox.

In the process of diagnosing the problem I have tracked back to simply trying to launch one of the Google sample apps (https://plushangoutstarter.appspot.com/static/simpleHangoutApp.xml) in the developer sandbox.

This fails in the same way as my app: the hangout says loading app along with a lovely animation but never loads.

I have tried this from different Google accounts and OS's but the problem is the same whatever.

The js console shows the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < login.corp.google.com/request?s=oz-autopush-full.plus.corp.google.com:443/u….google.com/js/api.js&maxAge=1200&authLevel=2000000&rpMode=v2&keyIds=Do0:2

Interestingly I can launch the hangout apps (mine and the sample ones) outside the sandbox. For example, https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/16fae425e33645b520c4b14f71adbdbba843f00d

To me it seems as if Google has deployed a breaking change but I can't believe that there would be no activity on twitter or the google plus developer group if they had.

My questions are:

1) Can anyone launch an app in the developer sandbox
2) If not, anyone got any idea what the problem is.

Thanks in advance for any help. As usual in these situations, I was planning on demoing my app to my colleagues in a couple of days to show them how cool the hangouts api is :(

Neil

Comment: We're having the exact same problem, Neil, since Friday (2/8/13). So whatever the problem is, it's on Google's end. I submitted a bug report on the Developers site for hangout but it needs more stars to get noticed.

Comment: There were a number of similar posts on the google plus group with a response to one of them from Google (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-plus-developers/V3eljFxR-2Q). Seems to be resolved now tho'. Phew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem on Google's side over the weekend and has now been corrected.